# position ul to centre inside a fixed div

Tags: css

I would like to horizontally center the menu. It could be done by assigning `margin-left` for `#navigation`, but the main items can increase and also the screen size.

Tried changing `ul#navigation {float:left;}` to

`ul#navigation {position:absolute;left:0;right:0;margin:0 auto;}`, but did not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/RLtkq/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu">
  <center>
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="sub_navigation">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="sub_navigation">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Navigation 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </center>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    min-width:200px;
}

ul#navigation {
    float:left;
}

ul#navigation li {
    float:left;
    border:1px black solid;
    min-width:200px;
}

ul.sub_navigation {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}

ul.sub_navigation li {
    clear:both;
}

a,a:active,a:visited {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RLtkq/1/).

Changes are here

```
ul#navigation {
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#navigation li {
    border:1px black solid;
    min-width:200px;
    display: inline-block; /* replaced float:left; */
}
```

Comment: when I hover over the second main item, the submenus for both 2nd and 3rd Mains slide down. And...Also, the 3rd main item has 10 sub items which now show up in 3 rows, instead of one.

Comment: Try `ul#navigation > li { display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 1):

Changing the display of the `#navigation`'s `li`s to `inline-block` seems to solve the issue:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLtkq/3/)

You get a gap on the right-hand-side, though. This can be eliminated with negative margins.